# What is the proper way to shutdown a ZeroMQ Subscriber?

Tags: c++, zeromq, ros

I am using the `PUB/SUB` model in ZeroMQ inside ROS.

The `SUB`-subscriber is allowed to stop just by pressing a <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**C**</kbd> in the terminal.

However, every time, when I actually press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it stops by throwing the following error:

```
^Cterminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'
  what():  Interrupted system call
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <zmq.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "node_name", ros::init_options::AnonymousName);
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Publisher pub;

  //  Prepare context and publisher
  zmq::context_t zmq_context(1);
  zmq::socket_t zmq_socket(zmq_context, ZMQ_SUB);
  zmq_socket.connect("tcp://192.168.1.20:9001");

  std::string TOPIC = "";
  zmq_socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, TOPIC.c_str(), TOPIC.length()); // allow all messages

  int timeout = 1000;  // Timeout to get out of the while loop since recv is blocking
  zmq_socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));

  while (ros::ok())
  {
      zmq::message_t msg;
      int rc = zmq_socket.recv(&msg);
      if (rc)
      {
          //receive data and prepare it for publishing
          pub.publish(data);
          ros::spinOnce();
      }
  }

  // Clean up the socket and context here
  zmq_socket.close();
  zmq_context.close();

  return 0;
}
```

**How to avoid the error so as to shut down the subscriber properly?**

Comment: Try running your program with gdb, the stack trace should show you where the exception is thrown (you need to compile with debug symbol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the issue is caused by `int rc = zmq_socket.recv(&msg)` hence I did following improvements-

1. I used `try` and `catch` block
2. Set `ZMQ_LINGER` as suggested by @user3666197

Below is the code snippet-

```
int linger = 0; // Proper shutdown ZeroMQ
zmq_socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_LINGER, &linger, sizeof(linger));

std::string socket_address = "tcp://192.168.1.20:9001";
zmq_socket.connect(socket_address.c_str());

ros::Duration duration(0.1); // in seconds (100 ms)
while (ros::ok())
{
    zmq::message_t msg;
    int rc = 0;
    try
    {
        rc = zmq_socket.recv(&msg);
    }
    catch (zmq::error_t& e)
    {
        ROS_DEBUG_STREAM("ZMQ Error. " << e.what());
    }
    if (rc)
    {
        unsigned char* byte_ptr = static_cast<unsigned char*>(msg.data());
        const int msg_length = msg.size();
        // receive data and prepare it for publishing
        pub.publish(data);
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
    else
    {
        ROS_DEBUG_STREAM("Pointcloud recv() returned 0");
        duration.sleep();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Without details about how the Ctrl+C was being trapped and handled, I would always add ( C++ binding details may differ version to version ):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    zmq_socket.connect(    "tcp://192.168.1.20:9001" );
    zmq_socket.setsockopt( ZMQ_LINGER, 0 );              // ALWAYS
    ...

    while( ROS::ok() )
    {
       ...
    }
    std::cout << "SIG:: will .close() after ROS::ok()-loop exit" << std::flush;
    zmq_socket.close();

    std::cout << "SIG:: will .term()  after a Socket()-instance .close()'d" << std::flush;
    zmq_context.close();

    std::cout << "SIG:: will return 0 after a Context()-instance .term()'d" << std::flush;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check it and get back to you later.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem still exists. I found a way to add [Custom SIGINT Handler](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown) but I am not sure how to integrate ZerMQ with it.

Comment: And where the exception actually sprung off? Right on the Ctrl+C handling, on a _socket.close(), on a _context.close(), where? Would you kindly post the value of the errno-signalled error ?

Comment: I put the following code `int code = zmq_errno(); auto message = zmq_strerror(code);` inside `if (rc){}` block after `ros::spinOnce();`. It prints following error `Resource temporarily unavailable`. However, I am still not sure from where exactly this exception is being thrown. Also, I noticed that sometimes I am not getting any exception after pressing `Ctrl+C`. But it is very rare.

Comment: Well, in any kind of control-loops ( the more in a ROS-case ), I would avoid every blocking- or potentially-blocking-steps. It means, rather use either a zero-timeout **`.poll(..)`** to sniff for a presence of any incoming message ( before deciding about to read any, that was confirmed to be already waiting in the local-side buffer ), or go a bit more brute way, to try to straight **`.recv( .., ZMQ_NOBLOCK )`** + handle the **`EAGAIN`** error-state. This, in both cases, effectively avoiding both the blocking per-se and the risk of killing "across" a still waiting state inside a blocking-mode.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried `.recv( .., ZMQ_NOBLOCK )` and found the loop became faster since it is in non-blocking mode. I am yet not sure how to handle `EAGAIN` state. The error still persists. Any suggestions?

Comment: First, it is **not any error**, it is **rather an unhandled exception** that appeared after some incident, colliding with any of the defined API rules, has happened. An initial starting point for this hunt for exceptions might be something like this >>> http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Comment: Setting the option zmq linger is a good habit, i usually tend to set it at the end - right before zmq_socket.close().